# How to combine the results of Gabor filter in OpenCV

Tags: java, filter, opencv3.0

I'm trying to enhance an image of fingerprint by using gabor filters in OpenCV for Java with a bank of 4 filters (4 theta):

```
private Mat enhanceImg(Mat myImg){

      // prepare the output matrix for filters
    Mat gabor1 = new Mat (myImg.width(), myImg.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat gabor2 = new Mat (myImg.width(), myImg.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat gabor3 = new Mat (myImg.width(), myImg.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat gabor4 = new Mat (myImg.width(), myImg.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat enhanced = new Mat (myImg.width(), myImg.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

      //predefine parameters for Gabor kernel 
    Size kSize = new Size(31,31);

    double theta1 = 0;
    double theta2 = 45;
    double theta3 = 90;
    double theta4 = 135;

    double lambda = 30;
    double sigma = 24;  
    double gamma = 1;
    double psi =  0;

       // the filters kernel
    Mat kernel1 = Imgproc.getGaborKernel(kSize, sigma, theta1, lambda, gamma, psi, CvType.CV_32F);
    Mat kernel2 = Imgproc.getGaborKernel(kSize, sigma, theta2, lambda, gamma, psi, CvType.CV_32F);
    Mat kernel3 = Imgproc.getGaborKernel(kSize, sigma, theta3, lambda, gamma, psi, CvType.CV_32F);
    Mat kernel4 = Imgproc.getGaborKernel(kSize, sigma, theta4, lambda, gamma, psi, CvType.CV_32F);

      // apply filters on my image. The result is stored in gabor1...4
    Imgproc.filter2D(myImg, gabor1, -1, kernel1);
    Imgproc.filter2D(myImg, gabor2, -1, kernel2);
    Imgproc.filter2D(myImg, gabor3, -1, kernel3);
    Imgproc.filter2D(myImg, gabor4, -1, kernel4);

    //enhanced = gabor1+gabor2+gabor3+gabor4 - something like that

    return enhanced;
}
```

Now, my problem is how to combine those results, gabor1, gabor2, gabor3 and gabor4, in order to get the entire enhanced image. 
I tried to use `Core.add(src1,src2,dst)` or

```
Core.addWeighted(enhanced , 0, gabor1, 1, 0, enhanced );
Core.addWeighted(enhanced , 1, gabor2, 1, 0, enhanced );
Core.addWeighted(enhanced , 1, gabor3, 1, 0, enhanced );
Core.addWeighted(enhanced , 1, gabor4, 1, 0, enhanced );
```

, but seems to do a kind of subtract and finally I get an image almost white.
 
Hope somebody can help me. I'm using Java but C++ implementation is very similar.

**EDIT:**
Here are the images of the input and results:
Input Img:
[image]

Img gabor1:
[image]

Img gabor2: 
[image]

Img gabor3:
[image]

Img gabor4:
[image]

And finaly the added (with addweighted) Img:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I think I got the solution of my problem. 
My input image (myImg) is of type CV_8UC1, but gabor kernels wrok with type CV_32F or CV_64F. So I had to convert myImg to that type before processing:

```
myImg.convertTo(myImg, CvType.CV_32F);
```

Also, I defined gabor1...4 as CV_32F type instead of CV_8UC1.
Then, I applied `Core.addWeighted(...)` to all 4 gabor filters (like above in my question), and I got the expected result.
It's a bit silly, but it's a common mistake (I think).